# Запретить показ сайта, когда перешли по ip

Tags: nginx

У меня есть два сайта, которые запущены на одном сервере. Сайты на nodejs, на https. Один располагается на домене, а другой  - на субдомене. При переходе на ip сервера, где развернуты сайты, показывается сайт на основном домене. Я хочу, чтобы при переходе на ip показывалась страничка 403 forbidden (при использовании и http, и https). 
Я пробовала сконфигурировать /etc/nginx/sites-available/default следующим образом

```
server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name _;
      location / {
         deny all;
      }
}
```

Это привело к тому, что при переходе непосредственно на http:// вылетала ошибка  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, а на https:// показывался сайт, но с неверным ssl сертификатом.
Как мне нужно сконфигурировать nginx, чтобы получить желаемый результат?
ОС на сервере Ubuntu 18.04, Nodejs v12.16.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can create two virtual hosts in Nginx. One for default access and
>   another for domain specific.
>
> Then you can restrict access for default access or redirect to your
>   domain as per your choice.

(https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151042/only-allow-access-to-nginx-server-when-using-the-full-domain-name-and-not-the-ip)

Можно создать два виртуальных хоста в нжинксе. Один для доступа по умолчанию, а другой для доступа по домену.

Затем ограничить доступ по ип или вообще редиректить на домен (как удобней/что подходит по задаче)

```
server {
listen      80 default_server;
listen      [::]:80 default_server;
server_name "";
return      444;  # тут код ошибки
#return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri; или можно раскомментить это и сделать редирект по домену
}

server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "www.example.com" # (тут ваш домен);
    ...
    ...
}
```